# Pasting code in SublimeText2 uses odd indentation

Tags: indentation, sublimetext2, sublimetext

If I have some code like:

```
function foo() {
  doStuff()
}
```

And I paste it at the point just before 'X' below:

```
     function foo() {
       X
     }
```

Sublime ends up pasting something like

```
     function foo() {
       function foo() {
  doStuff()
}
     }
```

Rather than what textmate does:

```
    function foo() {
      function foo() {
        doStuff()
      }
    }
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: If you look at the `Edit` menu, you should have an alternative `Paste and Indent`.

Answer (score 1):

Per @Joachim's suggestion this behavior is provided by 'paste and indent'. This can be made the default action by swapping around the 'paste' and 'paste and indent' shortcuts in Preferences -> Keybindings.

```
{ "keys": ["super+shift+v"], "command": "paste" },
{ "keys": ["super+v"], "command": "paste_and_indent" },
```